# ODI OSCOMMAND to move all the files from one path to another except todays file

Tags: oracle

```
find //C://Source_dir -type f! -name sample_file*$(date +%Y%m%d)* -exec mv {} //D://target_dir// \;
```

The above command is working in UNIX, but when I use this command in ODI OS COMMAND it is throwing error.

Comment: Please edit your question so as to include the error you are receiving.

Comment: Error im getting as ODI-30038 OS command return 2